# Exclusive gateway after parallel gateway in a process?

Tags: modeling, gateway, bpmn

I wanna know how such a process can be modeled in BPMN,

Once the package is dropped out by the forklift, two parallel actions are peformed: (1) a docker will inspect the package (this stream ends at this point); (2) forklift will check if there are other packages to move otherwise, the process ends.

For me, there will be two gateway, first parallel gateway followed by an exclusive gateway. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Best

Comment: from the text i guess you are overthinking it. 
The text says: start event -> activity "package dropped", then in parallel -> parallel gateway "+" splitting up the process flow into activities (1) and (2) on their own sequence flows -> afterwards you need a merging parallel gateway to get the two forked sequence flows into one sequence flow -> then the end event follows.

Answer (score 1):

You need one parallel gateway after the initial activity (drop package), after which the activities (1) and (2) are carried out in parallel.
I do not see an exclusive choice between activities in your process description, so there seems to be no need for an exclusive gateway.

Recommendation for further reading on BPMN gateways:

- https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/bpmn/bpmn-gateway-types